# cassandra cache store to Infinispan server 6.0.0.CR1

Tags: java, caching, infinispan

Hi is there a good document available to configure cassandra cache store to Infinispan server 6.0.0.CR1?
In one of the POST i found that this is not a good recommendation is there a reason why and was it ever addressed in the latest releases?
https://community.jboss.org/thread/195716